# Check if list is the reverse of the other list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a prolog predicate called flip(Lst1, Lst2) that holds if the first list is the reverse of the second list and vice versa.

For instance: `flip([a, b, c, d], [d, c, b, a]).` and `flip([a], [a]).`
should both return true, while `flip([a, b], [b, c]).`
should return false.

My first thought was to reverse the first list and then compare it with the second list, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: What did you write ?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out this works

```
flip([],[]).
flip([H|T],R) :- 
    flip(T,RevT),
    append(RevT,[H],R).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse built-in for this.

```
flip(List1,List2):-
    reverse(List1,ReverseList),
    List2=ReverseList.
```

**Examples:**

```
?- flip([a,b,c],[c,b,a]).
true

?- flip([c],[c]).
true

?- flip([a,b,c],[c]).
false

?- flip([],[]).
true
```

Comment: Why not **flip(List1,List2):-
    reverse(List1,List2).**

Comment: Would it be possible to not use the built-in?